# Show alternate class using ng-if in Angular

Tags: angularjs, view

I am trying to show `true` and `false` value for each data coming from an API in a table. For `true` , `<td>` is

```
<td><span class="label label-success status-active" title="Active">{{x.exist}}</span></td>
```

So when the value of `{{x.exist}}` is `true` as mentioned in API then span will be `label-success status-active" title="Active"`. Else if false then span will be `label-default status-disabled" title="Disabled"`.

I did this in my view but showing no result

```
<span ng-if="x.exist == 'true' " class="label label-success status-active" title="Active">
```

How can I do this in if-else in angular view ?

Comment: u can use ng-class directive

Comment: Try `ng-if="x.exist == true "` or `ng-if="x.exist "`

Comment: Can you show what data comes from the API?

Comment: @HpLam It will work only for `true` value , `false` were not displaying. I need to show both.

Comment: @31piy `{"ID":2,"exist": false},{"ID":23,"exist": true}`

Comment: @WhoAmI doent below code work for your  for such case ?

Comment: @WhoAmI, Can you use `ng-class` instead of `ng-if`

Comment: @HpLam No I afraid . I need to change the whole View for this. I thought of using ng-class , but it wouldn't be applicable in my case.

Comment: @WhoAmI, So try use 2 `ng-if="x.exist "`  and `ng-if="!x.exist "`

Comment: @HpLam This will either display true and false. I need both. Seems Taylor Rahul's answer is working

Comment: @TaylorRahul Ya i tried , its working just the UI for false is getting different. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the code with below for the span you have added it will show the class and title both based on x.exist values

```
<span ng-class="(x.exist) ? 'label-success status-active' : 'label-default status-disabled'" title="{{(x.exist) ? 'Active' : 'Disabled'}}" > {{x.exist}}</span>
```

Comment: It's working but the UI is getting little bit different. I will figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Can you vote this, so that others can know about this ?

Answer (score 0):

try

to display true value

```
<span ng-if="x.exist" class="label label-success status-active" title="Active">
```

to display false value

```
<span ng-if="!x.exist" class="label label-success status-active" title="Active">
```

Also there are ng-show and ng-hide

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: This will show only `true` value in the View not `false`